# how to send an otp to email using twilio in react-native

Tags: react-native, email, twilio, one-time-password

I have to send an otp to the user's email using twilio. Is there a proper way to do it? I cannot find any proper documentation aur blog telling me how to do it. I am working on react-native android project.

Comment: I believe this question is asking too many things at once. Are you wondering how to generate the One Time Password in your application? Or are you simply wondering how to send a generated password via Twilio? You should close/delete this question and research one or both of those questions individually. I think the answers you're looking for will come up if you break your problem into parts. If they don't, feel free to ask more focused questions on the topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @spicy.dll I need to know how to send a generated password via twilio

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088299/send-a-text-message-sms-with-twilio-using-react-native?rq=1

Comment: You should really be doing this from a server. The reason there's no documentation is because it's a security risk to make the required REST calls from a client machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The documentation for sending verification codes to an email address using Twilio Verify is here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/email.

As @spicy.dll has mentioned, you should make the API requests to Twilio from a server you control and not from your React Native application. If you make requests from your React Native app you would need to embed the API credentials somehow, and a malicious user could decompile your application, extract your credentials and abuse your Twilio account.

So, follow the docs above, host the code that calls the API and your credentials on a server and make requests to that server from your application.

Comment: But, what if I want to implement it on the front-end? Is there a way?

Comment: Implementing it in the front end is a security risk, as described. You should implement the API requests on a server, to protect your account credentials, then make requests to that server from your application.